# получение Unix timestamp для пост запроса для 9 полей с разницей в 2 минуты, не могу сделать чтоб секунды и миллисекунды тоже были рандомно

Tags: python, unix, timestamp

Есть сайт который фиксирует время заполнения полей профиля, полей 9.

```
email_acquired_timestamp=1670073915028&start_completed_timestamp=1670073873777&start_timestamp=1670073872044&tos_acquired_timestamp=1670073916700&name_acquired_timestamp=1670073883629&birthday_acquired_timestamp=1670073889624&cp_acquired_timestamp=1670073907835&pw_acquired_timestamp=1670073913436&gender_acquired_timestamp=1670073897572
```

Вот в такой формате выходят данные после отправки заполнения.

Как на Python сделай данную генерацию timestamp

Мой код

```
def __init__(self):
        data = get_info_account()
        number = get_number()
        n = random.randint(100,1000)
        self.id = uuid.uuid4()
        self.email = number['phone']
        self.activation_id = number['activation_id']
        self.password = data['password']
        self.fName =    data['firstname']
        self.lName =    data['lastname']
        self.birthday = "19%s-%s-%s"%(random.randint(91,99), random.randint(1,12), random.randint(1,28))
        self.access_token = ""
        self.user_agent = ''
        self.start_timestamp = datetime.now()
        self.completed_timestamp = datetime.now()+timedelta(minutes=4,microseconds=n)
        self.name_timestamp = datetime.now()+timedelta(minutes=7)
        self.birthday_timestamp = datetime.now()+timedelta(minutes=9)
        self.gender_timestamp = datetime.now()+timedelta(minutes=13)
        self.cp_timestamp = datetime.now()+timedelta(minutes=15)
        self.pw_timestamp = datetime.now()+timedelta(minutes=16)
        self.email_timestamp = datetime.now()+timedelta(minutes=18)
        self.tos_timestamp = datetime.now()+timedelta(minutes=20)


    def register(self):
            data = sorted([
                ('phone',self.email),
                ('firstname',self.fName),
                ('lastname',self.lName),
                ('gender','F'),
                ('password',self.password),
                ('allow_local_pw','true'),
                ('birthday',self.birthday),
                ('session_id','eb6b65bf-83a1-402a-94af-59a2329fcb77'),
                ('consent_standards_test_group','test'),
                ('play_service_version','-1'),
                ('additional_email_acquired_timestamp',str(self.email_timestamp.timestamp()).replace('.','')),
                ('start_completed_timestamp',str(self.completed_timestamp.timestamp()).replace('.','')),
                ('start_timestamp',str(self.start_timestamp.timestamp()).replace('.','')),
                ('tos_acquired_timestamp',str(self.tos_timestamp.timestamp()).replace('.','')),
                ('name_acquired_timestamp',str(self.name_timestamp.timestamp()).replace('.','')),
                ('birthday_acquired_timestamp',str(self.birthday_timestamp.timestamp()).replace('.','')),
                ('cp_acquired_timestamp',str(self.cp_timestamp.timestamp()).replace('.','')),
                ('pw_acquired_timestamp',str(self.pw_timestamp.timestamp()).replace('.','')),
                ('gender_acquired_timestamp',str(self.gender_timestamp.timestamp()).replace('.','')),
```

Comment: неужели в стандартнейших модулях для работы со временем ничего не нашлось? Или просто не искал?

Comment: Искал нашел, написал но проблема в том что при инициализации класса и его данных , unix время берется текущее для всех полей. У меня не получается сделать так что бы время было для каждого поля разное, как при заполнении через веб форму

Comment: вот это и нужно писать в вопросе, включая код, инициализации класса

Comment: у меня такой код работает, добавляется указанная разница

Comment: Да, прошу прощения не совсем точно описал, данный код работает но меняет только как я и указал в коде минуты, и у меня получается минуты разные а секунды и миллисекунды  одинаковые, не могу сделать чтоб они были рандомно

Comment: ну так добавьте в timedelta еще секунды и миллисекунды.

Comment: у меня не получается сделать чтоб там были рандомно данные секунд и милисекунд

Comment: Реши проблему, спасибо

Comment: Ваш вопрос должен примерно звучать так: у меня есть такой код, который делает то-то. Я хочу, чтобы между таймстампами была случайная разница в секундах/микросекундах. Пытался сделать это так (тут должен быть опять код), но не получилось потому что (тут описание того, как именно не получилось). А если вы в вопросе пишете "как построить дом", а на самом деле интересует какого диаметра должна быть водопроводная труба, то сложно ожидать, что кто-то об этом догадается.

Comment: Понял хорошо учту на будущее, прошу прощения за не ясность

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Допустим так:

```
import random

now = datetime.now() # чтоб каждый раз не дергать генерацию, можно просто сохранить в переменную
self.start_timestamp = now
s = random.randint(10,60) # случайное число от 10 до 60
self.name_timestamp = now + timedelta(seconds=s) # добавляем эту случайную разницу
```

Можно генерировать случайное число перед формированием каждого поля, тогда все таймстэмпы будут разные. По аналогии можно сделать минуты и миллисекунды.

Comment: Да спасибо так даже лучше)